# Vaadin Charts – Put Title and Legend on same row?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-charts

In [Vaadin Charts 2](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts), is there a way to get the [`Title`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Title.html) and [`Legend`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html) to appear on the same row? I mean, can both appear above the chart, or both below the chart?

Putting them on the same horizontal line would save vertical space. Those saved pixels are even more precious when presenting multiple charts together on a page.

Answer (score 0):

## `setVerticalAlign`

You can get them nearly even on the same horizontal line by calling [`setVerticalAlign`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html#setVerticalAlign(com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.VerticalAlign)) on the [`Legend`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html) itself. Use constants defined in the [`VerticalAlign`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/VerticalAlign.html) enum.

```
final Configuration configuration = myChart.getConfiguration();
configuration.getLegend().setVerticalAlign( VerticalAlign.TOP );
```

[image: screen shot of Vaadin Charts 2 chart with legend at the top next to title]

## Version 1 versus 2

Note that this positioning of the legend area changed between Vaadin Charts 1 and 2. To quote [the doc](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html#setStyle(com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.style.Style)) ([HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com) in the engine behind Vaadin Charts):

> In Highcharts 1.x versions the position of the legend area was determined by CSS. In 2.x, the position is determined by properties like align, verticalAlign, x and y, but the styles are still parsed for backwards compatibility.